# Find the range of values $k$ can take given that, for real $x$, $f(x) = \frac{x^2+3k}{x+k}$

Tags: quadratics

I'm trying to find the range of values $k$ can take given that, for real $x$, $f(x) = \frac{x^2+3k}{x+k}$ can take any real value. These are the steps I've taken so far:

$$
xy + ky - x^2 - 3x = 0
$$

Which gives us $a=-1$, $b=(y-3)$, $c=yk$. Using the discriminant:

$$
(y-3)^2 - 4(-1)(yk) \ge 0 \\
y^2 + y(-6 + 4k) + 9 \ge 0
$$

Taking the discriminant again, we have $a=1$, $b=(4k-6)$, $c=9$ which gives us:

$$
(4k-6)^2 - 4(9) \ge 0 \\
k(k-3) \ge 0
$$

So using the table method:

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
\space & k \le 0 & 0 \le k \le 3 & k \ge 3 \\
k & \text{-ve} & \text{+ve} & \text{+ve} \\
k-3 & \text{-ve} & \text{-ve} & \text{+ve} \\
k(k-3) & \text{+ve} & \text{-ve} & \text{+ve} \\
\end{array}
$$

So it clearly seems that the range is $k \le 0, k\ge3$ - but the listed answer is $0 \le k \le 3$, which doesn't make sense because that results in a negative value and invalidates the inequality equation. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After getting 
$$y^2+(-6+4k)y+9\ge 0,$$
what you need is
$$(-6+4k)^2-4\cdot 1\cdot 9\color{red}{\le} 0$$
instead of
$$(-6+4k)^2-4\cdot 1\cdot 9\ge 0.$$

Comment: Can you elaborate? Why taking the discriminant in the first place?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I suspected. But I didn't understand the switch to less than

Comment: @hohner: Do you understand the relation between the sign of the discriminant and the number of real roots of $ax^2+bx+c=0$?

Comment: If the discriminant is $>0$, then there are 2 distinct real roots. If it's less than 0, there are no real roots (but 2 complex roots).

Comment: @hohner: Right. Then, consider the parabola $Y=y^2+(-6+4k)y+9$. We want the range of $k$ such that $Y=y^2+(-6+4k)y+9\ge 0$ for **all $y$**. So, $y^2+(-6+4k)y+9=0$ must not have two real roots (having one real root is fine, which means the parabola is tangent to $y$-axis), so we need $D\le 0$ instead of $D\ge 0$.

Comment: @mathlove I got it - thank you :)

Comment: @hohner: Glad to help you! You are welcome.